# Why is my Receiver not Receiving Broadcast?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-pendingintent, proximity

I'm having difficulty using/understanding BroadcastReceivers and IntentFilters. I have the following code in my Test activity. Test activity contains a .addProximityAlert, if the .addProximityAlert is triggered I want to broadcast to the Test2 receiver. I get an error when I test this. What am I doing wrong?

Test Activity:

```
public class Test extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    LocationManager lm;
    ... 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
        ... 
        final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.proxalert.Test2";
        Intent alert = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alert, 0);

        lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        context.registerReceiver(new Test2(), filter);
```

Test2 Receiver:

```
public class Test2 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        Boolean entering = arg1.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
        if (entering) {
        //toast notification "welcome"
    }
    ...
```

Comment: post the exception stack

Comment: Please use LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "error". If you do not understand it, please copy it and paste it into your question via the "edit" link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by registering the receiver in the android manifest, rather than trying to register the receiver dynamically in test1. this website really helped:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers

Answer (score 2):

Test extends BroadCast receiver, so it has to be notified of a broadcast to get activated. Are you sure that's what you want to do ?

Is it really a test a la Android ? I don't think so. So if you just that code to work remove Test class, create an activity with a button and execute your code in Test when the button is clicked.

Comment: @thedeepfield did any answer match your requirements ?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, but could you accept the answer as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi to use BroadcastReceivers and IntentFilters to like this under your Activity (or Service) :

```
             broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {//global BroadcastReceiver
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                String action = intent.getAction();
                //Action receive
            };
```

Intent Filter :

```
        IntentFilter intentfilterTime = new IntentFilter(); 
        intentfilterTime.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);//receive battery level change
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentfilterTime);
```

Add all action you want to receive. 
Your code doesn't work cause you use a broadcast inside another i don't think it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply register both of your BroadcastReceiver in the same time and control enabling, disabling them by simple approach like

- Using static/non-static boolean variable
- Using Preferences to hold key-values

**for example:**

```
public class Test extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    LocationManager lm;
    ... 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
    ... 
            final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.proxalert.Test2";
        Intent alert = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alert, 0);

        lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        Test2.someStaticVariable = true;


public class Test2 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean someStaticVariable;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    if (!someStaticVariable){
        return;
    }

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        Boolean entering = arg1.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
        if (entering) {
        //toast notification "welcome"
    }
    ...
```